# django ModelChoiceField: how to iter through the instances in the template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to get access to the instances of a ModelChoiceField to render them the way I want in a template by displaying several fields of the instances.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    mychoices = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ObjectA.objects.all(), widget=forms.RadioSelect(), empty_label=None
    )
```

This does not work:

```
{% for choice in form.mychoices %}
     {{ choice.pk}}
{% endfor %}
```

I also tried to use the queryset but it does not render anything

```
{% for choice in form.mychoices.queryset %}
     {{ choice.pk}}
{% endfor %}
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
{% for choice in form.mychoices.field.queryset %}
    {{ choice.pk }}
{% endfor %}
```

Notice the extra `.field`. It's a bit strange the first time you come across it, but it gives you what you want. You can also access the `choices` attribute of that object, instead of accessing queryset directly, but you'll need to access the first element of the choice to get the PK of the instance, like this:

```
{% for choice in form.mychoices.field.choices %}
    {{ choice.0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Indeed, it's a bit strange to use the field attribute, I thought being already on the field. :)